# mod_rewrite ..cloaking specifics?

Tags: wordpress, apache, mod-rewrite

I've installed a WP theme that has a portfolio function - this creates /skills (for categories) and /portfolio (for entries). At the risk of 'breaking' things I do not understand by rifling through the code and changing every instance of 'skills' to 'shooting', is there a way to have mod_rewrite change /skills to something else and display it as such (even though the actual 'static url' would still be skills?

Current hierarchy:

- /skills
- /skills/weddings
- /skills/headshots

[click on portfolio entry within weddings]

- /portfolio/john-jane

Ideally:

- /shooting/
- /shooting/weddings
- /shooting/headshots

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Current code:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
RewriteRule /shooting/(.*)$ skills/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

I believe they both need to be functional though, as WP will continue to internally link to /skills/

Answer (score 0):

The way your current rules work, a request for `/shooting/weddings` would be sent to index.php in the line `RewriteRule . /index.php [L]` and the subsequent line would not be read. If you move the line `RewriteRule ^shooting/(.*)$ /skills/$1` up above the two `RewriteCond` lines and modify it to read like what I just wrote, that should make `/shooting/weddings` silently rewrite to `/skills/weddings`, which would then be fed to index.php.

Edit: Updated rules below. Initially I thought you just wanted to add /shooting to respond the same as /skills, which it does now, but now I think you also want someone loading /skills to be redirected to /shooting as well. The skills RewriteRule redirects all /skills traffic to /shooting. Once the user is redirected, they then hit the shooting RewriteRule, which silently rewrites them to /skills, which is then picked up by WordPress.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^skills/(.*)$ /shooting/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^shooting/(.*)$ /skills/$1
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Comment: `# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^shooting/(.*)$ /skills/$1
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress` like this? Same issue: http://alexmasters.is/shooting/headshots vs http://alexmasters.is/skills/headshots

Comment: Would it be worth mentioning that wordpress is in /wp/ and my htaccess file is in the root?

Comment: Updated based on my interpretation of your comment ... also, very nice shots on that site!

Comment: The solution I ended up using was: RewriteRule ^shooting/(.*)$ /skills/$1 [L,NC,P] immediately under RewriteBase /

Comment: I'm currently getting a 404 from /shooting/headshots whereas /skills/headshots is working. One note on the rule you just mentioned - the "P" flag should not be there, it is for proxy requests to another server and requires a full URL: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/flags.html#flag_p

Comment: Should be working now. My software seems to like to upload old files after I'm done with them - and it won't work without the P.